# Get size of JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, size

I am trying to draw a line from (0,0) to the center of the panel. No line is drawn because getWidth() and getHeight() in DrawingPanel constructor return 0. I guess this is because the frame is not visible yet. How can I get the size of the panel then?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DrawingApplication extends JFrame {
    static int CenterX;
    static int CenterY;

    public DrawingApplication(){
        setTitle("Drawing Application");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        DrawingPanel pnlDraw = new DrawingPanel();
        add(pnlDraw);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawingApplication drawingApp = new DrawingApplication();
        drawingApp.setVisible(true);
    }
}


class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
    int CenterX, CenterY;

    public DrawingPanel(){
        CenterX = getWidth()/2;
        CenterY = getHeight()/2;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2.drawLine(0, 0, CenterX, CenterY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches. The simplest would be these:

1. Update the size using a `ComponentListener` and update the size, when `componentShown` or `componentResized` is triggered.
2. Simply get the size each time you paint the `JPanel`.